# Constructor failing in inherited class python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the correct way of calling a constructor in an inherited class in python?

For example,

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.z = z
        # super().__init__(x, y) # <== works
        super(x, y) # <== throws TypeError: must be type, not int

a = A(2, 3)
b = B(2, 3, 4)
```

Is it possible to call a constructor without invoking the **__init__()** method from the base class?

Comment: Did you read the `super()` documentation carefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `super()` wrong; you need to create the object passing in the current class and `self`, then reference an inherited attribute on that:

```
super(B, self).__init__(x, y)
```

`super()` then uses `type(self).__mro__` to search the full inheritance tree in Method Resolution Order (MRO), starting at the next position past `B`, to find the attribute you want. Here you are looking for `__init__`, so `type(B).__mro__` is searched first for `B`, then starting at the next entry, for the `__init__` attribute, which is then bound to `self` for you. You end up with a call to `A.__init__(self, x, y)` this way.

Note that `super()` can be used to find *any* inherited attribute in the MRO, it is not just useful to find a base implementation for the current method.

`super()` can only be used in *new-style classes*, which means in Python 2 you *must* start your inheritance tree with `object`:

```
class A(object):
```

`object` is automatically part of your inheritance tree in Python 3.

Comment: So, the first argument is the base class, the second a reference to the current object and then the actual constructor invocation?

Comment: @Sebi: the first argument is the *current* class, not the base class. This is important, because the current  class determines the full inheritance hierarchy and thus the method resolution order. `super()` acts as a proxy, searching the MRO for you for *any attribute*, it is not just useful for the current method.

Comment: The exception "TypeError: must be type, not classobj" is still being thrown

Comment: @Sebi: You are using Python 2 then; make `A` inherit from `object`, as `super()` only applies to new-style classes.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
super(B, self).__init__(x, y)
```